# get the date:time by xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

currently I'm using xsl to get the min and max value of @last_updated_time in a sharepoint list, the type is string (like 9/14/2012 1:26:23 PM)

so how can I display the earliest and latest time?

P.S. I try to remove all things but number,then convert to the int, then do the compare, but how to convert that, can anybody show me an approach?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find it much easier to manipulate dates and times in XSLT (especially in XSLT 2.0) if you use international format (2012-14-09T13:26:23) rather than US localized format. So first, if your data is in US format, write code to translate it to ISO format. (That's a simple exercise in string manipulation).

Once you're there, you can use the XSLT 2.0 min() and max() functions to find the earliest and latest in a set of dates or date/time values. Or in XSLT 1.0, you can sort them and select the first and last in sorted order.